# adding fonts to ghostscript 9.10

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

Windows 8

The official documentation says to just edit the Fontmap file.

There are 12 "fontmap" files inside lib. Which one am I supposed to edit?

Let's say I want to add the "Arial" font and have it be a substitution for any font in the Arial format. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well here is what i do in this case,i add the below parameters to my ghostscript :

```
-sFONTPATH=%windir%/fonts -dEmbedAllFonts=true
```

Lets suppose you want to add the Arial font to the fonts list, you will refer to the path that has 
all the fonts and Ghostscript will use that fonts to substitute the missing ones, if your font is not available you will have to donwlad it and install it in the c:/windows/fonts path, as per [this](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=87) fonts path in windows 8 must be the same as previous versions of windows

Now this is the normal scenario, but for yours you can use the answer of this question 
"How do I specify custom substitutions on Windows?" [here](http://ghostscript.com/FAQ.html)

Comment: The last link is broken :(

Answer (score 1):

You could start by mentioning the operating system you are using. Windows differs markedly from Linux in this instance, and various Linux distributions differ in the way they package Ghostscript. However the file you want is almost certainly not in the 'lib' sub directory, those are examples for specific OSs. Try looking in Resource/Init for the file called Fontmap.GS

Be aware that if your version of Ghostscript has been compiled with a ROM file system (the default) then you will need to use the -I switch to include the directory in the search path, or the -sFONTPATH switch to add the directory as a font directory (don't use this one for Resource/Init...)

The file Fontmap.GS contains instructions at its head for adding new entries.

Comment: I can't find any Resource/Init directory

Comment: Windows ships by default with the ROM file system, and does not include the source for that. If you want the Resources directories then you need to download a copy of the Ghostscript source. You will then either need to build without the ROM file system, or use -I to add the downloaded resources to the search path. Or you can create a Fontmap file (if required) in each font directory you want to include and specify those directories using -sFONTPATH. See the reply from user1283633 above.